Close this thing
i'm a blender beginner and i wanted to make a gun for practice, the only problem is that when i was modeling i had a problem  so i removed the wrong part and now i have to close this hole but i dont know how to.
Hope someone can help me


if someone writes anything i will probably reply tomorrow cuz its night in europe

What's up with the title? I think you should edit the question and make the title informative. They are important, because people answering questions are looking at the title in a list first, so they need to know, what this is about. Also titles contain keywords that help other people facing similar issues find your question and hopefully answers to it when searching the web. If it's a question about closing a hole in geometry, you should clearly ask something like "How do I close a hole in my mesh object?"

Hello and welcome. Please use a title that matches the content of the post. It should read like a question, be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the problem so that anyone searching for similar issues is likely to find this. Remove anything superfluous, avoid using words like "this", "help with", "issue" or "question about", instead describe what "it" is. Remember, your title is the first thing visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on it. See What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"

Select the loop surrounding the hole, press Ctrl+F and select Grid Fill. Then you can adjust the settings in the panel on the bottom left, if needded.
For this to work you have to have an even number of vertices (for example 32, not 31)

Just to illustrate the Grid Fill feature.
To get predictable results, select two opposite edges, with equal number of vertices.



Thanks man! i would never expect such a good replym

No problem, feel free to ask more questions if anything else comes up ;)
